# Open Pst in thunderbird

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, thunderbird

I have a pst file which contains all my outlook backups. I want to import those mails into my thunderbird in Ubuntu 10.10. Though I can import it using Evolution mail client. But i like to stick to thunderbird. Any ideas, suggestios ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atlast i imported my outlook 2007 backup files into thunderbird using readpst. No other solutions worked for me.

```
1.sudo apt-get install readpst

2.readpst -r pstfilename
```

Changes the output format to Recursive. This will create folders as named in the PST file, and will put  all  emails  in  a  file called   "mbox"   inside  each  folder.  These  files  are  then compatible with all mbox-compatible email clients.Then just imported the mbox file into thunderbird and i got my mails back

I am using
Ubuntu 10.10
Thunderbird 3.1.8

Comment: I get the error: "Opening PST file and indexes...
unknown index structure. Could this be a new Outlook 2003 PST file?
Error opening File" You imported your Outlook 2007 files? This su****s!

Comment: Yes, I have the exact same problem. With multiple PST files.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've come out with two pages:

A way to import pst files manually:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files#Linux

Or using an addon in thunderbird:

http://obm.org/doku.php?id=projects:pst_import