# import pst/ost file in os x mail

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, apple-mail, pst

I've just moved from Windows to OS X. I have lots of emails stored in Outlook pst and ost format. How can I import this mails into the Mac Mail App?

The mails should be stored localy on the Mac. I don't want to import them into an IMAP account because it's my multi Gigabyte Mail Archive of the last 15 years. But it would be very handy if the mail search would search inside this archive as well.

Update:

So far I found 2 Tools which are able to export to mbox format which can be imported in Mac Mail App.

- [O2M](http://www.littlemachines.com/) stops on the first signed email.
- [MessageSave](http://www.techhit.com/messagesave/) sliently looses all attachements.

Are there any tools without this limitations which can export pst/ost to mbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all I ended up using the `readpst` command line tool which is recommended in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/271286/open-pst-in-thunderbird) post. It can easily be installed using [home brew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: `readpst` works for Mac too?

Answer (score 0):

I just joined the apple iCloud and found an other possibility to transfer your mails. If you decide to synchronize your windows outlook emails via the iCloud you will get them on your mac mail app as well.